# What is the underlying difference between IBM MQ persistent and non persistent transactions?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

While testing my application which uses IBM Websphere MQ, I encountered an issue while committing messages in MQ.

Basically there is one single batch which reads from oracle DB and processes the information and writes to queue.

Multiple instances of the same batch application can run concurrently with some parameters, so the DB records never overlap and will always be different, but they both write messages to the same queue.

Both instances commit messages after 1000 messages are generated and put in queue.

The max uncommitted size of the queue manager is 1000.

**1st run:**
Default persistence of QM: Persistent
Max uncommitted messages: 1000

Faced error when both instances were run simultaneously.

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2053' ('MQRC_Q_FULL').
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
```

**2nd run:**
Default persistence of QM: Non-Persistent
Max uncommitted messages: 1000

Both batches run successfully.

**3rd run:**
Default persistence of QM: Persistent
Max uncommitted messages: 10000

Both batches run successfully.

I want to know the reason why 2nd run was successful even when max uncommitted messages was 1000.

How does IBM MQ transactions work internally? Is it due to the caching mechanism used by MQ for persistent messages? Or due to the fast speed of non persistent messages that the error was never encountered?

Comment: What is the MAXDEPTH of the queue you are putting to?

Comment: MAXDEPTH is 5000. That is why it was difficult to understand why MQRC_Q_FULL was encountered.

Comment: Only 2 producers?

Comment: @JoshMc Yes exactly

Comment: You say "Default persistence of QM", do you mean the queue you are putting to has DEFPSIST(YES)?  Are you setting persistence in your program?

Comment: Was the queue empty before you started?

Comment: @JoshMc Yes DEFPSIST(YES) configuration exists in the server for that particular queue.

Comment: @MoragHughson Yes, queue is empty before start of the execution. We have a script for cleanup process.

Comment: What did the depth show when you get 2053.  Can you please show your code.

Comment: If you are certain the queue is empty before you start and this is repeatable, I would be looking at the 5000 messages on the queue after the 1st run and looking at what the extra 3000 messages are; what application put them; what their content is etc.

Comment: @JoshMc Sorry, but unfortunately the code implementation I would not be able to show due to compliance issues. But one additional point is that I noticed when Queue is persistent, it stores the messages in some logs. Is it due to the size exhaustion of the log file?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most likely reason for this behaviour is, that you don't specify MQPMO_SYNCPOINT in the put message options in your code, but rather rely on the implicit syncpoint option to put messages transactionally:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=multiplatforms-implicit-syncpoint

But we can't be sure without seeing your code.

I think this is a good description of the differences between persistent and non-persistent messages:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/message-persistence-faqs

But I think the most important difference is that persistent messages survive a QM restart, while non-persistent messages are deleted on restart.